# Understanding a mathematical statement in image processing

Tags: image-processing

I am reading a document on Image processing and couldn't analyze a statement in it.

> For any $k \in \Psi_s$, the family of values $\{u[\varphi(p+l)+k-l]:l \in \Psi_s \}$ is
>   representative of the value of...

The variables are explained below
$k$,$p$,$l$  - pixels
$u()$      - image intensity
$\Psi_s$     - patch of size 5x5 or 9x9 and so on.
$\varphi()$    - mapping function corresponding to that pixel

how do i get the values mentioned? i have tried to check other documents but couldn't find any.

Comment: Could you type the rest of the text too?

Comment: Welcome to DSP SE. Anytime you mention some publication it is good to include it. The more detailed question is, answer will be better and appear quickly.

Comment: Perhaps scan the page you're having trouble with and include it as an image (or post a link to the image; you may not have the rep to include an image directly here).

Comment: The document is "comprehensive framework for image inpainting" from IEEE. [imagelink](http://imgur.com/xAFuz5U).